# How can I create a ChatGPT print Animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, text, core-animation, combine

I have created a small ChatGPT clone using [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/) to communicate with his/her API.
How I can create a print-style animation when the response comes from the API?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State var text = ""
    @State var models = [String]()

    var body: some View {

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach($models, id: \.self) { $string in
                    Text(string)
                }
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    TextField("type here ...", text: $text)
                    Button("Send") {
                        send()
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.setup()
            }
            .padding()
    }

    private func send() {
        guard !text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else { return }
        models.append("Me: \(text)")
        viewModel.send(text: text) { response in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.models.append("ChatGPT: " + response)
                self.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75838356/how-to-convert-response-text-to-speech-using-avspeechsynthesizer these questions look very similar, is this homework?

Comment: this is not homework. it is aside project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split text by words or letters, and then add it one by one. Here is an example.

[image: Demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var letters: [String] = []
    @State private var text: String = "I have created a small ChatGPT clone using SwiftUI to communicate with his/her API. How can I create a print-style animation when the response come from the API?"
    @State private var displayText: String = ""
    @State private var animating: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(displayText)
                .frame(height: 100)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            Button(action: animate) {
                Text("Animate")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding()
                    .background(animating ? .black.opacity(0.75) : .black)
                    .cornerRadius(12)
            }
            .disabled(animating)
        }
        .padding()
    }

    private func animate() {
        animating = true
        displayText = ""
        letters = []
        letters = Array(text).map { String($0) }
        loop()
    }

    private func loop() {
        let pace = 0.05

        if !letters.isEmpty {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + pace) {
                displayText += letters.removeFirst()
                loop()
            }
        } else {
            animating = false
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you please attach code based on the current answer with HTTP async streaming response, much appreciated in advance